# Creating a webpage with persistent tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tabs

I'm trying to create a web page that has multiple tabs on the same page.  I need these tabs to persist through refreshing, and be able to redirect a user to the page with a specific tab.  Currently, I'm just using JavaScript and different divs for each tab, hiding all tabs then showing the chosen one.  But, upon refreshing or being directed to the page, the first tab is always the one open.

I have seen URLs of pages with tabs that use the following format:

> http://www.website.com/profile.php#tab

If that is an acceptable method of persistently tabifying a web page, how is this done?  And if that's just an incorrect observation on my part, how would I go about making these persistent tabs?

Comment: How about JavaScript cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of frameworks that provide this type of "hash" based navigation, or you could implement something on your own using the **jQuery hashchange** plugin, or using the **Backbone.js Router** class.

You could even implement something on your own:

```
var myTabClicked = function() {
    // display mytab
};

$('.mytab').bind('click', myTabClicked);

$(function() {
    if (window.location.hash == "#mytab") {
        myTabClicked();
    } else {
        // display default tab unless already displayed by default
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll implement this now!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function that is called in the body tag like so...

```
<body onload="Javascript:checkTab();">
```

To check if the page has refreshed like this...

```
function checkTab() {
if( document.refreshForm.visited.value == "" )
  {
    // This is a fresh page load
    document.refreshForm.visited.value = "1";
  }
else
  {
    // This is a page refresh

    // This checks the contents of the hash
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    // Insert code here like an if statement that checks
    // if the variable "hash" is the name of a specific tab.
    // If the hash is the name of a tab, unhide the tab
  }
}
```